# CSS - Trying to copy text-shadow

Tags: css, shadow

From this image https://www.dafont.com/img/illustration/d/i/digital_dot_roadsign.png, I would like to produce the same "DIGITAL DOT ROADSIGN" text as it appears on the top right. For the font, I use the classic code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: DDR;
  src: url(DigitalDotRoadsign.otf);
}
```

But for the text-shadow, I can't make it appear as strong as it appears on the image. I use `text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #823400` and for the third value I tried using very high numbers but it always looks kind of weak and thin (https://i.gyazo.com/bc771e5cfd7753985aeffd0c8b8770a8.png) How can I produce the `text-shadow` of the image?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your css, or maybe use a darker background color or lighter shandow color. I used the settings below and got this as a result. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtRDa.jpg

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: "Digital Dot Roadsign";
    src: url(DigitalDotRoadsign.otf);
}
* {
background-color: black;
font-family: "Digital Dot Roadsign";
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 100px;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgb(255, 196, 0);
color: yellow;
}
```